# Is there a way to defeat Vanguard (the first boss)?

Tags: demons-souls

In the fight with the first boss (the winged demon with the giant club) I died because it was so difficult.  The game does continue on afterwards. But I wonder, is it possible to defeat him, and do you get anything for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/954345-demons-souls/faqs/56319) seems to answer the question.

Here's the relevant part:

> ```
>                 BOSS BATTLE : VANGUARD [BV]
> ```
>
> This boss wasn't meant to be defeated,
>   but stories of the hardcore prevailing
>   are many.
>
> It has 2 slashes, a direct overhead
>   slash, and a horizontal forward slash.
>   Not only that, but it also has a body
>   press attack when players attempt to
>   flank it too much.
>
> A tactic for winning, is to stay under
>   it's sword arm, and keep slashing it, 
>   until it does it's body press attack.
>   At that point, roll back, and then 
>   resume slashing it.
>
> If you do win, you'll score yourself a
>   [Gripless] katana, and a [Grey Demons 
>   Soul]
>
> Either way, win or lose, you die. D:

Comment: Hes actually pretty easy, after 2 or 3 tries you will take him down no problem. When you are standing under his left/right hand, he can't hit you period. The only problem is when he does his stomp, roll the hell away and afterwards run right under his arm again.

Answer (score 1):

My roommate spent countless hours with that game last semester, so I do know that it is possible to defeat him and that you get something for it.  I also know that with those bosses, it often helps to go and train up for boss fights.

Sorry I can't remember specifics, though.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to time your rolls to go through his attacks. You're completely invincible through the middle part of the roll, so if you roll sideways when he swings, you can pass through his attacks.